# GCP Dataflow pub/sub to pub/sub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm using gcp pub/sub. If there was exception while accepting new message, I put it to dead letter queue.
I want to have an opportunity to reprocess message after reviewing. I tried to use Dataflow, but it just sends messages as soon as it came to dead letter queue.
Any advices how can I solve it?

Comment: @AishwaryShukla, there is a topic "newAccount". After 5 unsuccessful attempts to get ack for new message from subscriber, this message goes to dead letter queue topic.

Comment: And now you want to process message from dead letter topic again right?

Comment: Yes, you are right, but after reviewing this message only. I want to decide by myself: send it again or no. As I can see Dataflow could resend messages without reviewing.

Comment: I've stardet Dataflow's job pub/sub to pub/sub, to take messages from dead letter queue and resend it to topic "newAccount". Unfortunatelly I can not decide to resend message or not in that case

Comment: For temporary solution, maybe export data from dead letter topic to BigQuery using dataflow. Once you review the data, use any component to process and re-export data to pubsub from BigQuery. This way you can control when to export data. I know this is not ideal. But will help for short term. I will reply back if I find any solution.

Comment: Did what Aishwary told you about work? If yes @AishwaryShukla could you put it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

For temporary solution, maybe export data from dead letter topic to BigQuery using dataflow. Once you review the data, use any component to process and re-export data to pubsub from BigQuery. This way you can control when to export data. I know this is not ideal. But will help for short term.